# NullPointerException in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I have a class `Catalogue` to store info about it. Here i had just use two methods:

```
public void setCataName(String n)
    {cataName = n;}

public String getCataName()
    {return cataName;}
```

This is the code for my JFrame:

```
public class AddCataFrame extends JFrame
{
    JLabel lname; 
    JTextField tname;
    Catalogue catalogue;

    AddCataFrame()
    {
        super("Add New Catalogue");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lname = new JLabel("Name:", SwingConstants.LEFT);

        tname = new JTextField(15);

        textListener t = new textListener();
        tname.addActionListener(t);

        add(lname);
        add(tname);
    }

    class textListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {   
            //get the name from the textField after entered by user
            //then set it to the name of catalogue.
            //This is the place give me NullPointerException error.
            catalogue.setCataName(tname.getText()); 

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,catalogue.getCataName());
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure it out why give me a NullPointerException. Please help me.

Comment: Have you initialized `catalogue`?

Comment: Please see [What's a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). It's probably the most common exception you'll face, and IME in most cases, one of the easiest to catch (fix). So learn to debug your own.

Comment: What a kind of mistake I have made!! Sorry for wasting all your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you initialize your catalogue variable? You don't. Solution: initialize it first before trying to use it.

e.g.,

This only declares the variable:

```
Catalogue catalogue;
```

This declares **and** initializes it:

```
Catalogue catalogue = new Catalogue();
```

or this can initialize the variable if you want to use a Catalogue object passed into your class on creation:

```
AddCataFrame(Catalgogue catalogue)
{
    super("Add New Catalogue");
    this.catalogue = catalogue; // *************

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    lname = new JLabel("Name:", SwingConstants.LEFT);

    tname = new JTextField(15);

    textListener t = new textListener();
    tname.addActionListener(t);

    add(lname);
    add(tname);
}
```

---

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should inspect the line carefully that throws it, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: I am such noob, forget the basic things ,thank u. I will be more careful when coding further.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable catalogue is defined but never initialized. That's why you get the exception.

You should have a line like `catalogue = new Catalogue()`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialise `catalogue`. You should change

```
Catalogue catalogue;
```

to

```
Catalogue catalogue = new Catalogue();
```

Non-primitive fields are by default initialised to `null`, hence the `NullPointerException` on line

```
catalogue.setCataName(tname.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to initilaze cataloge

```
Cataloge  catalog= new Cataloge();
```